# Generic Entity Framework Pagination

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to write a generic way to provide pagination on my Link query to my MySQL database. However this required me to have a generic way to where, as the field used may differ from table to table. The issue i am facing it that Linq can't translate my generic types. Are there a way to do this that would work with Linq?

```
public static class PaginationExtentions {
    public static async Task<PaginationResult<T>> Pagination<T, J>(this DbSet<J> dbSet, Pagination pagination, Func<IQueryable<J>, IQueryable<T>>? select) where J : class {
        bool previousPage = false;
        bool nextPage = false;
        string startCursor = null;
        string endCursor = null;
        
        var property = typeof(J).GetProperty(pagination.SortBy);
        
        string after = pagination.After != null ? Base64Decode(pagination.After) : null;
        
        bool backwardMode = after != null && after.ToLower().StartsWith("prev__");
        string cursor = after != null ? after.Split("__", 2).Last() : null;

        List<J> items;
        if (cursor == null) {
            items = await (from s in dbSet
                           orderby GetPropertyValue<J, string>(s, pagination.SortBy) ascending
                           select s).Take(pagination.First)
                                    .ToListAsync();
        }
        else if (backwardMode) {
            items = await (from subject in (
                                                     from s in dbSet
                                                     where string.Compare( (string?)property.GetValue(s), cursor) < 0
                                                     orderby (string?)property.GetValue(s) descending
                                                     select s).Take(pagination.First)
                                 orderby (string?)property.GetValue(subject) ascending
                                 select subject).ToListAsync();
        }
        else {
            items = await (from s in dbSet
                           where string.Compare((string?)property.GetValue(s), cursor) > 0
                           orderby GetPropertyValue<J, string>(s, pagination.SortBy) ascending
                           select s).Take(pagination.First)
                                    .ToListAsync();
        }

        previousPage = await dbSet.Where(s => string.Compare((string?)property.GetValue(s), cursor) < 0).AnyAsync();
        nextPage = items.Count == 0 ? false : await dbSet.Where(s => string.Compare((string?)property.GetValue(s), (string?)property.GetValue(items.Last())) > 0).AnyAsync();

        var backwardsCursor = !previousPage ? null : "prev__" + cursor;
        var forwardsCursor = !nextPage ? null : items.Count > 0 ? "next__" + (string?)property.GetValue(items.Last()) : null;

        return new PaginationResult<T>() {
                                             Items = select(items.AsQueryable()).ToList(),
                                             TotalCount = await dbSet.CountAsync(),
                                             HasPreviousPage = previousPage,
                                             HasNextPage = nextPage,
                                             StartCusor = Base64Encode(backwardsCursor),
                                             EndCursor = Base64Encode(forwardsCursor)
                                         };
    }
    
    private static U GetPropertyValue<T, U>(T obj, string propertyName) {
        return (U)obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
    }
    
    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }
    
    public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see a lot of wrong code. Supply with test model and input data, and probably it can be fixed.

Comment: Don't try to do everything in one method. Filtering, ordering and paging are separate operations that can be coded completely independently. That's why it's perfectly possible to use a generic library like [PagedList](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Core/) to which you can offer a filtered and/or ordered query.

Comment: This code only handles the cursor pagination. I need to use Cursor pagination and not offset pagination to be able to integrate it with another framework that i need to use.